# What is the rationale behind this type of data input?

Tags: r, function, global-variables

The example is from the **rootsolve** package:

We have this function:

```
gradient(f, x, centered = FALSE, pert = 1e-8, ...)
```

in which f is a function and x is the data input in for of a vector

Now the following is an instance of the code being run:

```
logistic <- function (x, times) {
with (as.list(x),
{
N <- K / (1+(K-N0)/N0*exp(-r*times))
return(c(N = N))
})
}
# parameters for the US population from 1900
x <- c(N0 = 76.1, r = 0.02, K = 500)
# Sensitivity function: SF: dfi/dxj at
# output intervals from 1900 to 1950
SF <- gradient(f = logistic, x, times = 0:50)
```

My question is how does the code understand to use `times` in its routine. It's not defined globally and it is not part of the function input list either. Is it possible to pass inputs to a function when it is not defined in its structure? Does `...` play a role here?

Comment: You can read [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#The-three-dots-argument) or just type `rootSolve::gradient` at the console to see exactly how `f` is called in a way that includes the contents of `...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`...` is just a way of getting an extra arguments and passing them on to another function.

Simple example:

```
power.function <- function(x,power) { x^power }
apply.function <- function(f, data, ...) { f(data, ...) }
sample <- c(1,2,3)
apply.function (power.function, sample, power = 3)

# which is the same as

apply.function (power.function, sample, 3)
```

produces

```
> apply.function (power.function, sample, 3)
[1]  1  8 27
```

**EDIT**

To make it crystal clear, if you look at the source of the `rootSolve::gradient` you'll see the definition as

`function (f, x, centered = FALSE, pert = 1e-08, ...)`

and further down the call to

`reff <- f(x, ...)`

which is the same as described above in the example.